# Datatables with custom sort AND Bootstrap tooltips don't work together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, datatables, coldfusion-9

Datatables with custom sort AND Bootstrap tool tips don't work together

```
<td style="text-align : center" data-sort="#modifydate#">
    <img src="assets/icon/properties.png" title="Modified: 
       #request.stdDate(ModifyDate)#<br />
       By: #ModifyBy#<br />
       Created: #request.stdDate(CreateDate)#<br />
       By: #CreateBy#" />
</td>
```

Javascript in `application.js`

```
$("[title]").tooltip({ html: true });


$('#datatable').dataTable({
    "deferRender": true,
    "paging": false
    });
```

The sorting works ok, but the tool tips disappear.

The tool tips work ok with not custom sort.

Comment: I don't see any code in there related to Bootstrap's tooltips feature....

Comment: What do you mean by "custom sort"? Are you using a certain sorting plugin?

Comment: I am using sorting as outlined on: http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Comment: the tooltips don't show or stop showing up after sorting?
Are you doing something like this? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abbottmw/q5L9u7vw/3/)

Comment: After I add the data-sort, the tool tip no longer works when hovering.

Comment: What is the value for #modifydate#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this in js:

```js
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    'trigger': 'hover',
});
```

and check if they have `pointer-events: none` in CSS.